# displaying search results on a separate JFrame class

Tags: java, swing

I have been trying to manipulate my search button to read through my `.txt` files on my pc and return on a separate JFrame class the result. I can currently generate a specific file using the `FileReader` and the `BufferedReader` classes but i want to make it more dynamic which depends on the search parameter

```
public void searchResult() throws IOException {
    FileReader inputFile;
    try {
        inputFile = new FileReader("C:\\IO\\91.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inputFile);
        searchResult.read(br, inputFile);
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SearchResults.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }               
}
```

This is what i have to pick a specific file... I want to be able to make my file reader class to be able to pick that information from another class I call search

```
private void searchButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                     
    SearchTicket st = new SearchTicket();        
    st.setVisible(false);
    st.searchResults();
}                                                                                    
public void searchResults() {
    SearchResults sr = new SearchResults();
    super.dispose();
    sr.setVisible(true);
    try {
        sr.searchResult();
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SearchTicket.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us your current code, or an example, so that we can comment
 thanks

Comment: public void searchResult() throws IOException {
        FileReader inputFile;
        try {
            inputFile = new FileReader("C:\\IO\\91.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inputFile);
            searchResult.read(br, inputFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {            
        ex.PrintStackTrace();}
        
        
    //This is what i have to pick a specific file... i want to be able to make my file reader class to be able to pick that information from another class i call search

Comment: Code in comments is hard to read, and fragments may be misleading. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44843744/edit) your question to include a [mcve] that exhibits the problem you describe.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it dynamic, try using a [`jFileChooser`](https://www.mkyong.com/swing/java-swing-jfilechooser-example/). You can browse through all your directories and get the path of the file, even the file itself.

Comment: not sure how to use. dosent help the current situation